# Inference time and TFLOPS in pytorch

Tags: gpu, pytorch, profiler, inference

I am currently looking into the **half-precision inference time** of different CNN models using the torch.autograd.profiler using two different GPUs:

- Nvidia RTX 2080 Ti (**26.90 TFLOPS**) - done locally (better CPU)
- Nvidia T4 (**65.13 TFLOPS**) - done in the cloud

It took me by surprise that the 2080 Ti is **significantly faster** (half the time or less), independent of batch size, input resolution, and architecture even though it has less than **half the TFLOPS**.

Does anyone know why?

```
import torch
import segmentation_models_pytorch as smp # pip install git+https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models.pytorch

runs = 10
res = 512
bs = 8
is_half = True

m = smp.Unet(encoder_name='resnet101', encoder_weights=None)
m.eval()
m.cuda()
m.half()

t = torch.rand((bs, 3, res, res)).cuda()
t = t.half()

if is_half:
    m.half()
    t = t.half()

# warm up
with torch.no_grad():
    m(t)

cpu_time_ms = 0
cuda_time_ms = 0
for i in range(runs):
    with torch.no_grad():
        with torch.autograd.profiler.profile(use_cuda=True) as prof:
            m(t)
        cpu_time_ms += prof.self_cpu_time_total / 1000
        cuda_time_ms += sum([evt.cuda_time_total for evt in prof.key_averages()]) / 1000

cpu_time_ms /= runs * bs
cuda_time_ms /= runs * bs

print('res={}x{} cuda={:.1f}ms cpu={:.1f}ms'.format(res, res, cuda_time_ms, cpu_time_ms))
```

Example:

```
unet with resnet101 as backbone and batch size 8

t4
res=128x128 cuda=11.3ms cpu=3.0ms
res=256x256 cuda=14.5ms cpu=2.8ms
res=512x512 cuda=50.4ms cpu=7.3ms

rtx 2080 ti
res=128x128 cuda=7.5ms cpu=1.7ms
res=256x256 cuda=8.6ms cpu=1.8ms
res=512x512 cuda=21.1ms cpu=3.0ms
```

Comment: If you could provide the full script such that others could run this too it would be nice.

Comment: @Berriel added the full cude